# Replace for Java6+ Arrays.binarySearch in Java5

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Quite a simple question. I have a Java5 project where I need the Arrays.binarySearch(long[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, long key) method that is only available from Java6. Is there some library that provides this method. I checked the ArrayUtils class from Apache Commons, but there is not. I am not up for writing the search on my own :)

Comment: What prevents you from copying the method to your code?

Comment: Even though, in most circumstances, this kind of functionality will be provided for you (and I recommend using the standard implementation), it's still a good exercise to implement sorting/searching functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply take the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java/?v=source) for that class and bring it into your project.

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo If am not mistaken, linked code is from OpenJDK projects licensed under GPLv2 and cannot be used in closed-source projects. Maybe it's better to use the same class from [android class library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Arrays.java) that is apache2 licensed.